# Send email with plain text and html attachment

Tags: python

I'm trying to send email that contain both plain text in the body and html attachment. I've succeeded in adding the attachment but can't figure out how to add the plain text to the body. Any help is appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import smtplib, ssl
from email import encoders

def sendmail():
        subject = 'Subject here'
        body = "Shard Count: 248" #Need to add this to body in plain text
        senders_email = 'title@domain.com'
        receiver_email = 'security@domain.com'

        #Create a multipart message and set headers
        message = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
        message['From'] = senders_email
        message['To'] = receiver_email
        message['Subject'] = subject

        message.attach(MIMEText(html_file, 'html'))

        filename = 'logs.html'

        # Open file in binary mode
        with open(filename, 'rb') as attachment:
            # Add file as application/octet-stream
            part = MIMEBase('application','octet-stream')
            part.set_payload(attachment.read())

        # Encodes file in ASCII characters to send via email
        encoders.encode_base64(part)

        # Add header as key/value pair to attachment part
        part.add_header(
            'Content-Disposition',
            f"attachment; filename= {filename}",
            
        )

        # Add attachment to message and convert message to string
        message.attach(part)
        text = message.as_string()

        # Log into server using secure connection
        context = ssl.create_default_context()
        with smtplib.SMTP("smtp.domain.com", 25) as server:
            # server.starttls(context=context)
            # server.login(senders_email, password)
            server.sendmail(senders_email,receiver_email,text)
        
        print("Email sent!")
    sendmail()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program looks fine for sending email with html body and an attachment. For sending plain text body, you will need to make a minor modification. I have tested your code with html body and plain text body. I am attaching both the versions of the code below.

**The code with html body and an attachment is given below. I have tested this code at my end.**

```
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import smtplib, ssl
from email import encoders


html_body = '''
    <html>
        <body>
            <h1>Sample email header</h1>
            <p>Sample body</p>
        </body>
    </html>
    '''

def sendmail():
    subject = 'Subject here'
    body = "Shard Count: 248"  # Need to add this to body in plain text
    senders_email = 'amal@example.com'
    receiver_email = 'amalgjose@example.com'

    # Create a multipart message and set headers
    message = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    message['From'] = senders_email
    message['To'] = receiver_email
    message['Subject'] = subject
    # The message body gets set here. Here we can add html body or text body.
    # Syntax - message.attach(MIMEText(content, 'content-type'))
    message.attach(MIMEText(html_body, 'html'))
    # Name of the file to be attached
    filename = 'attachment.pdf'

    # Open file in binary mode
    with open(filename, 'rb') as attachment:
        # Add file as application/octet-stream
        part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
        part.set_payload(attachment.read())

    # Encodes file in ASCII characters to send via email
    encoders.encode_base64(part)

    # Add header as key/value pair to attachment part
    part.add_header(
        'Content-Disposition',
        f"attachment; filename= {filename}",

    )

    # Add attachment to message and convert message to string
    message.attach(part)
    text = message.as_string()

    # Log into server using secure connection
    context = ssl.create_default_context()
    with smtplib.SMTP("smtp.examplemail.com", 25) as server:
        server.starttls(context=context)
        server.login(senders_email, 'password')
        server.sendmail(senders_email, receiver_email, text)
    print("Email sent!")
sendmail()
```

If you want to send an email with plain text and an attachment, you just need a very minor change in the code. Make the following modification in the code.

```
text_body = "Hello, this is my text data in email"
message.attach(MIMEText(text_body))
```

**The updated code which sends emails with plain text body and attachment is given below.**

```
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import smtplib, ssl
from email import encoders

text_body = '''
            Hello, this is the sample text body. This program sends email with text body and an attachment.
            I hope this helps
            '''

def sendmail():
    subject = 'Subject here'
    body = "Shard Count: 248"  # Need to add this to body in plain text
    senders_email = 'amal@example.com'
    receiver_email = 'amalgjose@example.com'

    # Create a multipart message and set headers
    message = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    message['From'] = senders_email
    message['To'] = receiver_email
    message['Subject'] = subject
    # The message body gets set here. Here we can add html body or text body.
    # Syntax - message.attach(MIMEText(content, 'content-type'))
    message.attach(MIMEText(text_body))
    # Name of the file to be attached
    filename = 'attachment.pdf'

    # Open file in binary mode
    with open(filename, 'rb') as attachment:
        # Add file as application/octet-stream
        part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
        part.set_payload(attachment.read())

    # Encodes file in ASCII characters to send via email
    encoders.encode_base64(part)

    # Add header as key/value pair to attachment part
    part.add_header(
        'Content-Disposition',
        f"attachment; filename= {filename}",

    )

    # Add attachment to message and convert message to string
    message.attach(part)
    text = message.as_string()

    # Log into server using secure connection
    context = ssl.create_default_context()
    with smtplib.SMTP("smtp.examplemail.com", 25) as server:
        server.starttls(context=context)
        server.login(senders_email, 'password')
        server.sendmail(senders_email, receiver_email, text)
    print("Email sent!")
sendmail()
```

Comment: Hey Amal, your solution works well. The only thing is that now the html file does not show in the body of the email like before. Do you know how I can get it back?

Comment: By the way, the email attachment is an html file. It doesn't necessarily need to be attached, but it has to show in the body itself. Having to download and open the file in the browser would be counter-productive, so a quick look at the body, and I'll know the server details.

Comment: If you are looking to attach the html content in the body of the email, you can use the earlier approach and include the text also as part of the html itself. For making the html clickable, you just need to create a hyperlink onclick in the html content.